# Обновление функционала после пул реквеста

Tags: git, git-pull, git-flow

Есть репозиторий с проектом. Я внес необхоидмые правки, реализовал новые фичи. Все это делалось в отдельной ветке сномером задачи 5131 (Git Flow). Затем, отправил все коммиты на Pull Request, после чего они были слиты в ветку develop. Сейчас появилась необходимость доработать код в 5131 добавив новый функционал. Как лучше поступить, создать ветку 5131-1 где добавить необходимые фичи или завести под это дело отедльную задачу со своей веткой?

Comment: создайте отдельную задачу, внутри задачи опишите, что она на основе 5131.

Comment: доработка - это исправление ошибки? новая фича?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понимаю, оба варианта выглядят так себе.

Делать другую ветку для той же задачи (если вы действительно её продолжаете, а не делаете новую связанную задачу) может не хотеться по эстетическим причинам: не держать больше одной ветки для каждой фичи в одном репозитории.

С другой стороны, если в этой ветке не будет изменений, произошедших после принятия pull request, высок риск отхватить merge conflict, когда придёт время делать слияние доделок, если до этих доделок в `develop` происходило что-то ещё.

При условии, что у вас репозиторий ведётся "консервативно" (без постоянных rebase с целью избавления от запутанных деревьев коммитов)...

## Можно совместить!

Можно сделать слияние `develop` в `feature/5131` (именно так, в обратную сторону!), после чего продолжить работу в этой же ветке как обычно.

Так работа над фичей продолжается в той же самой ветке, но при этом конфликты с изменениями, уже известными к моменту старта доделок, будут невозможны, т. к. работа начнётся с самого свежего состояния и разруленными конфликтами (если они были).

Comment: А разве можно комитить в ветку, после пулл реквеста?

Comment: @QuaternioNoir конечно. Реквест делается из ветки в ветку, пуш новых коммитов в фича-ветку добавит их и в реквест.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir, во-первых, пулл реквест - это не команда гита, а надстройка. Она может быть реализована разными способами. Или указанием ветки или указанием конкретного коммита (последнего в ветке на момент запроса). Во втором случае можно. Какой механизм используется - вы не указали.

Comment: Во-вторых, если произошел merge, значит ваш запрос уже отработан.

Comment: TFS и Git Flow.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir надо смотреть на то, как там реализованы пулл-реквесты, типично это реализуют "из в ветки в ветку", но как именно в TFS, я не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

В случае если поменялась интерпритация задачи и Вам необходимо доделать, переделать и особенно если необходимо **исправить** функционал в принятом пулл-реквесте, в первую очередь необходимо выполнить revert принятому реквесту.

`$git revert #merge-hash -m 1`

Таким образом Вы обезопасите других разработчиков команды от возможности использовать некорректный код.

Затем Вам необходимо выполнить merge в фиче-ветку ревёрт и затем выполнить revert ревёрт коммита т.н. двойной ревёрт. Двойной ревёрт нужен для того что-бы ваши изменения стали определятся в **общей** ветке develop. Без него git не сможет добавить отревёрченные изменения. 
После того как Вы доделаете/переделаете/исправите код по задаче, можно ещё раз выполнить пулл-реквест.

Более подробно о двойном ревёрте и подобой ситации можно [почитать здесь](http://lshnk.me/dvoinoi-reviort-ili-kak-zhit-posle-plokhogo-pull-rekvesta.html)

Comment: Используйте общепринятые аналоги терминов на русском или оригиналы латинскими буквами. "смёржить, отревертать" - не все поймут.